# Aren't DOM searches for elements with classes depth first?

Tags: html, css, dom, search

I was under the impression that when a browser (generally) searches for an element that has a class it is a depth first search.

Recently I was asked to put some code together for a colleague, and asked to identify forms on a page with the substring of 'webform' in the class. I knew there was a form on a page I tested and used the following JS:

```
document.querySelector("[class*=webform]")
```

However, this returned the body element of the page whose class attribute had the substring of 'webform' in it. Generally (this question being browser dependant) is the searching in the DOM for elements containing a certain class depth first? Is it totally implementation or browser dependant (as in querySelector will use one method and another function will use a different method)?

Many thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors

Comment: Isn't depth-first where the search starts at the root node of a document? In the case of a web page that would be `html`.

Comment: I should also add that since `querySelector` returns a single match, it will return the first match that it finds. In your case the search path would be `<html> → <body>`. `querySelector` can be used on any element. So you should be able to do `document.body.querySelector()` and find your form (as long as `webform` doesn't exist elsewhere as a class).

Answer (score 0):

@hungerstar is right. Apologies for the brain fart, seems I need to brush up on my trees a little!

So in conclusion, it proved that it is depth-first. Great!